# run jupyter on server

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, server, jupyter

i want to run jupyter from my server .
MY ip server is: 172.172.10.10.
I tried to pull image python with this command:

```
docker run -p 8888:8888 jupyter/scipy-notebook:33add21fab64
```

then i tried to connect to the container and install jupyter with

```
pip3 install jupyter
jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root
```

then from my host tried

```
    http://172.172.10.10:8888/?token=9bb378073cXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX2be61c
```

but got always this error **ERR_CONNEXION REFUSED**.
Does anyone knows how to do please. ??

Comment: on which port is jupyter running?

Comment: @SreeramTP ho should i do? to know it?

Comment: can you try ```jupyter notebook --ip 0.0.0.0 --no-browser --allow-root --port=8888```

Comment: -bash: --port=8888 : unkown command

Comment: instead of running jupyter like you mentioned in your Q, run it like I've mentioned in the comment above

Comment: @SreeramTP got same error !! :/ Thank you

Comment: **172.172.10.10** cannot authorize the connexion.

Comment: @SreeramTP have you an idea? pleasE?

Comment: try setting `--ip '*'` when starting the notebook, to bind to all interfaces. 

I have set this up before following the guide for config and ssh setup (https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/stable/public_server.html#running-a-public-notebook-server)

Comment: @stevejpurves i tried **--ip '*' ** and i got the same error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run hosted Jupyter on a server, you really want to use JupyterHub and not Just Jupyter.

I would suggest two readings:

- [The Littlest Jupyterhub (https://tljh.jupyter.org)](https://tljh.jupyter.org) for minimal single server install
- [Zero To JupyterHub (http://z2jh.jupyter.org/)](http://z2jh.jupyter.org/) for bigger deployment with kubernetes.

Docker by itself will be weird. Get it first to work with a simple `python3 -m http.server`. Once **that** works, you know your docker config is good, and move to bigger fish like Jupyter.

If you do not want JHub, you **really** want to use nginx in front of Jupyter to do ther ssl terminaison and other performance stuff to not get your server compromised.